# Compare google email id with email id in database and return user details

Tags: mongodb, flask, google-oauth

I have a database with some user details like name email password etc
When i log in using the mail account i need to check if the logged in gmail id is  in the database and if it is then fetch that particular users details and redirect user to the users profile

I have got the email id and the other user details that the gmail account provides using the scope as https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    access_token = session.get('access_token')
    if access_token is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    access_token = access_token[0]
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen, URLError

    headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth '+access_token}
    req = Request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo',
    None, headers)  
    try:
        res = urlopen(req)
    except URLError as e:
        if e.code == 401:
            # Unauthorized - bad token
            session.pop('access_token', None)
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        return res.read()
    return res.read()

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True)
    return google.authorize(callback=callback)

@app.route(REDIRECT_URI)
@google.authorized_handler
def authorized(resp):
    access_token = resp['access_token']
    session['access_token'] = access_token, ''
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@google.tokengetter
def get_access_token():
    return session.get('access_token')


I need to compare or check if the logged in email id user exists in the database and get that particular user's details and display it to profile page
```

Comment: What is the question? Which library are you using? I do not see a scope in your code requesting user info (email).

Comment: i m using flask-oauth

Comment: Well you answered one of my two questions and you did not get the hint to post your source code that showed your authorization request. How may we help you if you do not help us with requested information?

Comment: oauth = OAuth()
google = oauth.remote_app('google',
  base_url='https://www.google.com/accounts/',
  authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  request_token_url=None,
  request_token_params={'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'response_type': 'code'},
  access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  access_token_method='POST',
  access_token_params={'grant_type': 'authorization_code'},
  consumer_key=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  consumer_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)

Comment: thats my code where i have written the scope